# Enviando arquivos através de sockets - Python

Tags: python, socket

Estou estudando sockets, usando Python, e tentei fazer um script para enviar (Server) e receber (Client) arquivos através de sockets. Porém o script não funciona como o esperado, no arquivo final (recebido pelo Client) sempre falta alguns bytes e alguns outros bytes são modificados, como pude constatar pela análise do arquivo enviado e do arquivo recebido em um editor hexadecimal.

Tomei como base outros scripts pela internet (os testei, e funcionaram perfeitamente), porém desses peguei apenas a lógica para que pudesse construir o meu próprio. Mas ainda assim não consegui encontrar meu erro, que persistiu. Se conseguir, peço que me indique o erro que estou cometendo. Os meus códigos estão logo abaixo.

Obs: O arquivo de teste que estou enviando tem exatamente 6053 bytes, e o estou enviando de uma só vez, mas anteriormente estava percorrendo o arquivo em um loop e enviando o arquivo em partes menores. Mesmo assim não estava funcionando, tentei, pois, simplificar ao máximo o script.

**Server.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import socket
import os

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(('',1112))
print 'Socket criado!'
sock.listen(5)
print 'Esperando conexão...'
conn, addr = sock.accept()
print 'Nova conexão de',addr,'!'
#Abrir arquivo
flname = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\arquivo_teste.jpg'
fyle = open(flname, 'rb')
kar = fyle.read(6053)
conn.send(kar)
print 'Arquivo enviado!'
fyle.close()
conn.close()
sock.close()
```

**Client.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import socket
import os

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('127.0.0.1',1112))
flname = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\recebido.jpg'
fyle = open(flname,'w+')
print 'Iniciando...'
fyle.write(sock.recv(6053))
fyle.close()
sock.close()
print 'Arquivo enviado!'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que abrir o arquivo no modo binário - principalmente se estiver usando Python 3.x - isso é feito colocando-se a letra "b" depois do "w":

```
fyle = open(flname,'wb')
```

(Também não é necessário o "+" se você vai só escrever no arquivo).

Provavelmente é o único problema que você está tendo agora - mas leve em conta que o uso de sockets "puros" não é a forma mais apropriada de transferir arquivos entre sistemas diferentes. Isso por que sockets não tem a noção de "arquivo" ou "mensagem" por si mesmos - você acaba tendo que implementar um outro protocolo - por mais mínimo que seja, para conseguir usar sockets. Por exemplo: nesse caso você codificou no próprio programa o nome e o tamanho do arquivo que vai transferir. Mas num sistema em produção, essas informações teriam que vir pela rede também.

Protocolos de mais alto nível feitos por cima do socket existem - como http, ftp, rsync, o próprio git -  e estão disponíveis tanto diretamente na biblioteca padrão do Python, como existem vários pacotes auxiliares para facilitar seu uso.